# OpenTok subscribe to the same stream multiple times on mobile?

Tags: android, ios, opentok, tokbox

I am working with the OpenTok Android and iOS SDK... and I am not seeing any way to subscribe to the same stream multiple times (as in have multiple views showing the same stream). Is this possible? I have tried to accomplish this a few different ways, 1) By subscribing to the same stream multiple times (results in all-black views for every subscribed view), and 2) Adding the same view to multiple places (simply doesn't work). Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately the only way we were able to accomplish this was by modifying their library. Their library by default will detach from the previous view when you subscribe with another view, so we had to modify this.

Comment: Honestly, IMHO I would recommend you stay away from OpenTok if you are making anything more complex than a Google Meet or Zoom. Their SDKs are HEAVILY designed to work in a "contained environment" like these apps, and if you attempt to do ANYTHING outside this mandatory "single contained view", then you are essentially screwed. We have been moving to Twilio WebRTC because OpenTok is so terrible (messy source, forced flows, poor support, poor SDKs, etc...).

Comment: we have done a fairly complex app with OpenTok, we didn't have much choiche as they were the only provider which could broadcast a video chat through RTMP and that's what we needed. It's been a rocky ride, I agree with what you said about the source and everything else :D

Comment: Ah great! I am glad you were able to work through it. Sorry I wasn't more help. =/